# Looking For a Good and Easy solution

Tags: flutter, performance, dart

I am looking for a code which is work properly for flutter.
when we press on that small image it will show like this bigger image.

[image: I am looking for a code which is work properly for flutter. when we press on that small image it will show like this bigger image.]

Comment: EASE is a greater threat to progress than HARDSHIP.

Comment: thank for your comment but  i am self learned guy and I tried for week to find a solution but I don't find any solution..

Comment: You can actually achieve this with `GestureDetector` and on its `onTap` function, you can do setState the selected image.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Image(image: ResizeImage(MemoryImage(bytes), width: 50, height: 100))
```

You can try this.